# Getting code back from APK file generated by Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, dll, reverse-engineering

Before reporting as duplicate, please read the question!

Today I was decided to try get code from already compiled android application created in Unity engine. I found that in some apps is file `Assembly-CSharp.dll` (in /assets/bin/Data/Managed) where is practically all code, but in some apps there is only some symbols files. What are these files and how to get that code when there is no .dll files?

[image]

Comment: Maybe IL2CPP vs Mono?

Comment: @JeanLuc Yes. Thats it. Thanks you your response. Anyway I guess that there is no way to get that code easy as if it is compiled with mono?